# Why does Gulp fail to automatically re-process my JS upon changes?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

In my `gulpfile.js`, JS changes automatically trigger both `BrowserSync` reload and my JS processing task. But for some reason, although the reload does work, my JS task fails to correctly process JS changes and create new JS file in `dist/` folder. I have to restart Gulp for that. Why?

Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('../assets/styles/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/styles'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src(['../assets/scripts/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/scripts'))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1/my_site/new-front-page/',
  })
})

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'js', 'browserSync'], function() {
  gulp.watch('../assets/styles/**/*.scss',['sass']);
  gulp.watch('../**/**/*.php', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('../assets/scripts/*.js', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('../*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

EDIT:

Also tried the code below for the "js" task (see the 3 last lines compared to the code above), to no avail:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src(['../assets/scripts/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});
```

Comment: Please post your "default" task

Comment: If you only run `gulp js`, does that work correctly? Do the compiled files end up in the right place?

Comment: Just typing "gulp" doesn't do anything, I don't have a default task, I pasted my entire gulpfile.js content.

Comment: @drake035  Do you run `gulp` in the exactly same directory with `gulpfile.js`? I got this after running your code: `[19:00:35] Using gulpfile ~/*******/gulpfile.js      
[19:00:35] Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile                
[19:00:35] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile for
matting  `

Comment: @drake035  What edition of gulp are you using?

Comment: @blackmiaool: yes same directory. CLI version 3.9.1, Local version 3.9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43017532/1883001), you should change your `watch` task. But, you should have:

```
gulp.watch('../assets/styles/**/*.scss',['sass', browserSync.reload]);
gulp.watch('../**/**/*.php', browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch('../assets/scripts/*.js', ['js', browserSync.reload]);
gulp.watch('../*.html', browserSync.reload);
```

When the styles and scripts change, we rerun the tasks (`sass` & `js`) and reload the page.

I tried your code with these changes and it worked. The answer is based on [Google Web Starter Kit's gulpfile.babel.js](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js#L176) which has:

```
gulp.watch(['app/scripts/**/*.js'], ['lint', 'scripts', reload]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Why can't I award the bounty? The button is gone, is that thing time-limited? How can I still award?

Comment: You are welcome. It seems like there's no way to award it after the time period!

Comment: Argh, I don't really see the point in that rule. Anyway sorry mate :(

Comment: No need to be sorry. It's fine with me @drake035

Comment: Remember that the calls in the watch task array ['js', browsersync.reload] run in PARALLEL - they are not guaranteed to finish in any particular order.  From the docs : "Note: The tasks will run in parallel (all at once), so don't assume that the tasks will start/finish in order."  https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md  Hence my approach below is better.  Personally, I use gulp4,0 and gulp.series to solve race issues.  In any case, @BaderSur's answer is otherwise no different than mine and potentially could run the reload prior to finishing the js task.

Answer (score 3):

Try executing the **js** task like I have mentioned below

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
gulp.src(['../assets/scripts/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
watch(['../assets/scripts/*.js'], function() {
    gulp.start('js');
 });
});

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'watch']);
```

Writing this way helped me. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have to re-run "gulp watch" in order to get the last JS in my dist/ folder...

Answer (score 2):

Your gulp.watch for js changes does not actually call your 'js' task.  That is why you have to rerun the 'watch' task to see any changes.

```
gulp.watch('../assets/scripts/*.js', browserSync.reload);
```

It just reloads the browser but doesn't call the 'js' task.  Change to:

```
gulp.watch('../assets/scripts/*.js', ['js']);
```

and

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src(['../assets/scripts/*.js'])
  .pipe(jshint())
  .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
  .pipe(concat('main.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/scripts'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did have that before then I removed it while trying to fix the issue. Just re-added it. It doesn't seem to help at all...

Answer (score 0):

try `end` event:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src(['../assets/scripts/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/scripts'))

    .on('end', browserSync.reload)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have to re-run "gulp watch" in order to get the last JS in my dist/ folder...

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('watch', ['sass' , 'js' , 'browserSync'], function() {
gulp.watch('../assets/styles/**/*.scss' , ['sass']);
gulp.watch('../**/**/*.php' , browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch('../assets/scripts/*.js' , browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch('../*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

`The array of tasks that need to be completed, before gulp runs watch, processes the array in reverse order. So browserSync runs first, then js and then sass. You just need to reverse the order to ['browserSync','js','sass'].
That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the watch task as follow:

```js
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('../assets/styles/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/styles'))
  .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src(['../assets/scripts/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'js'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1/my_site/new-front-page/',
  });

  gulp.watch('../assets/styles/**/*.scss',['sass']);
  gulp.watch('../**/**/*.php').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('../assets/scripts/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('../*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

The problem is probably the way you're reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Modularize your code a bit. easy to make changes !

Your gulpfile.js

`var build = require('./gulp/build');
gulp.task('build:dist', build.buildDist);
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('build:dist'));`

In your build.js inside gulp folder make a series of task that you want to perform

`var buildDev = gulp.series(
    clean,
    gulp.series(
        lint,
        injectDev,
        moveAndFlattenFonts,
        moveAndFlattenAdminFonts,
        moveJsonToApp
    )
);
var buildDist = gulp.series(
    buildDev,
    //move all the things
    gulp.parallel(
        moveHtml,
        moveIndexHtml,
        moveAdminHtml,
        moveBowerComponentImagesToDist,
        moveAdminComponentImagesToDist,
        moveImagesToDist,
        moveFontsToDist,
        moveIconsToDist,
        moveJsonToDist,
        moveServerConfigFiles,
        moveScriptsToDist,
        moveScriptsToAdminDist,

        moveCssToDist,
        moveCssToAdminDist,
        moveAndTemplatifyHtml

    ),
    replaceRevisionedPaths,
    injectToIndexDist,
    injectToAdminDist
);`

and run gulp build:dist as a starting task