# Gulp reload browser after task is finished

Tags: javascript, gulp

Inside my gulp task, I want to fire reload my browser using `browserSync.reload` **after** the tasks have been finished. Currently my `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['build'], function () {

    browserSync.init({
        notify: false,
        server: "./" + dist
    });

    gulp.watch("/**/*.html", ['html']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("/**/*.md", ['html']).on('change', browserSync.reload);

});
```

Currently the first thing gulp does is `[BS] Reloading Browsers...` and then `[12:54:12] Starting 'html'...`.

How can I change this to first run `html` and on finish `browserSync.reload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need the `on.change` listener, you can specify the reload like this:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['build'], function () {

    browserSync.init({
        notify: false,
        server: "./" + dist
    });

    gulp.watch("/**/*.html", ['html', browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch("/**/*.md", ['html', browserSync.reload]);

});
```

**EDIT**

As *Mark* said, running both tasks in parrallel could generate some errors, a better solution could be:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['build'], function () {
    browserSync.init({
        notify: false,
        server: "./" + dist
    });

    gulp.watch("/**/*.html", ['reload']);
    gulp.watch("/**/*.md", ['reload']);
});

gulp.task('reload', ['html'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});
```

Comment: See my comment here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015697/why-does-gulp-fail-to-automatically-re-process-my-js-upon-changes/43366820#comment76387418_43366820  and why running your 'html' task and browsersync.reload in parallel is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
gulp.task('reload', function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});
 
gulp.task('bs', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://strona.pl/"
    });

    gulp.watch("./css/*.scss", gulp.series('sass', 'deploy', 'reload'));

    gulp.watch('./**/*.php').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./*.php').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```